# 'venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, flask, cmd, virtual

There is a similar question but it does not deal with my error:

On trying to install a virtual environment using CMD in the E drive, I used this command:

```
E:\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate
```

The error that occurred was:

```
'venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What exactly are the steps required to install flask - the documentation was followed step by step and did not work.

You can trace my steps, and I keep getting stuck here. What am I doing wrong?

```
E:\>mkdir myproject

E:\>cd myproject

E:\myproject>python3 -m venv venv

E:\myproject>py -3 -m venv venv
Error: Command '['E:\\myproject\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 3221226505.

E:\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate
'venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\myproject>
```

Note: You'll see that I've followed the steps for creating a virtual environment from here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#virtual-environments

I also tried the following, but also resulting in an error:

```
E:\myproject>py -3 -m venv venv
Error: Command '['E:\\myproject\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 3221226505.

E:\myproject>
```

I tried to enter the venv itself and tried this - again a different error. I think I am missing something very basic.

```
E:\myproject>cd venv

E:\myproject\venv>venv\Scripts\activate
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I also tried: (based on a stackoverflow answer)

```
E:\myproject\venv>pip install virtualenv
```

Again, an error.

and

```
E:\myproject\venv>py -3.8 -m venv venv
```

still, nothing.

Another point that may be of interest/relevance:

In the E drive ,I installed PYTHON 3.8.3 in the root directory. I am obviously creating the various folders e.g. myproject also in the root directory. E: mkdir myproject

Does the path affect anything? I am now deinstalling and re-installing python.

I am ensuring that I am checking the little tick that says "add python to environment path" (which I hadn't earlier).

On reinstalling: this occured:

```
E:\>mkdir myproject

E:\>cd myproject

E:\myproject>python --version
Python 3.8.3

E:\myproject>python3 -m venv venv

E:\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate
The system cannot find the path specified.

E:\myproject>
```

A slightly different error, I note, but still CANNOT FIND THE PATH related.

Finally, I tried creating the dir and venv in the actual folder where python was is installed: Still, an error

```
E:\>cd Python installation
E:\Python installation>mkdir myproject
E:\Python installation>cd myproject
E:\Python installation\myproject>python3 -m venv venv
E:\Python installation\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate
The system cannot find the path specified.
E:\Python installation\myproject>
```

Comment: So `python3 -m venv venv` worked?

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: I'd say it did because 1) it didn't raise any errors and 2) you were able to `cd` into `venv`, which presumably wasn't there before you ran the command.

Comment: ForceBru -I'm not talking about the venv part - but the activate. That's the part that is not working

Comment: Does the `venv` directory exist? Does `venv\Scripts` exist?  Does `venv\Scripts\activate` exist?

Comment: It did...but now even that is not appearing in 'myproject', So now - no

Comment: The following, doesn't come up with an error. It just does nothing: 
E:\Python installation\myproject>python3 -m venv venv

E:\Python installation\myproject>

Comment: ---------------------------
Serenity's Unicode Text Editor
---------------------------
NT Status 0xC0000409 (-1073740791 32 bit and 3221226505 64 bit)

Windows Error 0x502 (1282)



**NT Status Message:**

The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.





**Windows Error Message** The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frustrating, as I followed the official flask tutorial and it didn't work. This, however, did:

I hope someone finds this useful.

```
E:\Python installation\myproject>py -m venv env
E:\Python installation\myproject>env\Scripts\activate
(env) E:\Python installation\myproject>
```

Note that in the first step i typed in py -m venv env
instead of py -m venv venv (as suggested on the official docs)

Comment: py -m venv env is the official documented command. Good to know you succeeded!

Comment: I use PyCharm as a visual management tool for venv. It removes the hassle. After creating the venv folder, if you prefer coding in VSCode, simply open the project folder and it will automatically activate the environment for you. If you want easily maintainable envs, it could be a thing to try.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

Go to your project directory (myproject) and then:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: E:\myproject>.\venv\Scripts\activate
'.\venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\myproject>

Comment: Thanks for your try - I didn't downvote you. But no, it didn't work.

Comment: So, guess the question is not clear for me. I thought you were trying to activate an existing virtual environment. You were not able to create one?